# Pandas GroupBy and sort_values don't work as expected

Tags: pandas, sorting, group-by

I have dataset which has columns:

```
Unnamed: 0         int64
id                object
number_from       object
number_to         object
time              object
```

And I applied this function on it:     `data1.groupby('number_from').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time'))`

I get something like this:

```
Unnamed   id     number_from  number_to       time
17699  d20b3e          934           674  2017-07-03 06:36:20.000  
17700  d20b81          934           674  2017-07-03 06:36:22.000  
17701  d20b96          934           674  2017-07-03 06:36:23.000  
**17703  d20c17        612           235  2017-07-03 06:36:28.000**  
17707  d20db5          934           658  2017-07-03 06:36:45.000  
17708  d20de9          934           658  2017-07-03 06:36:47.000  
17710  d20e05          934           658  2017-07-03 06:36:49.000  
17711  d20e41          934           658  2017-07-03 06:36:51.000  
17712  d20e73          934           658  2017-07-03 06:36:53.000 
17713  d20ecc          934           702  2017-07-03 06:36:57.000  
17714  d20ef1          934           702  2017-07-03 06:36:59.000 
17715  d20f32          934           702  2017-07-03 06:37:01.000  
17716  d20f77          934           702  2017-07-03 06:37:03.000  
17717  d20f8d          934           702  2017-07-03 06:37:05.000 
17718  d20fd8          934           262  2017-07-03 06:37:08.000 
17719  d21017          934           262  2017-07-03 06:37:11.000  
17720  d21032          934           262  2017-07-03 06:37:12.000  
17721  d2103e          934           262  2017-07-03 06:37:13.000  
17722  d2106d          934           262  2017-07-03 06:37:15.000
**17723  d210c4        396           048  2017-07-03 06:37:19.000** 
17725  d21147          934           691  2017-07-03 06:37:24.000  
17726  d21167          934           691  2017-07-03 06:37:26.000
```

Note: this is just the subset of the values in the dataframe that I have.
It just sorted values and it did not grouped.

And I want to group and  to sort time values in each group independently of others.

I also tried `data1.sort_values(['time'], ascending=False).groupby('number_from')` but the result is same. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need sorting by multiple columns together, but first convert column `time` to datetimes:

```
data1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['time'])
#if need to compare integers
data1['number_from'] = data1['number_from'].astype(int)

data1.sort_values(['number_from','time'])
```

EDIT:

Tested both solution, working same:

```
data1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['time'])

df1 = data1.sort_values(['number_from','time'])
print (df1)
             id  number_from  number_to                time
Unnamed                                                    
17723    d210c4          396         48 2017-07-03 06:37:19
17703    d20c17          612        235 2017-07-03 06:36:28
17699    d20b3e          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:20
17700    d20b81          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:22
17701    d20b96          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:23
17707    d20db5          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:45
17708    d20de9          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:47
17710    d20e05          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:49
17711    d20e41          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:51
17712    d20e73          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:53
17713    d20ecc          934        702 2017-07-03 06:36:57
17714    d20ef1          934        702 2017-07-03 06:36:59
17715    d20f32          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:01
17716    d20f77          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:03
17717    d20f8d          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:05
17718    d20fd8          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:08
17719    d21017          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:11
17720    d21032          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:12
17721    d2103e          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:13
17722    d2106d          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:15
17725    d21147          934        691 2017-07-03 06:37:24
17726    d21167          934        691 2017-07-03 06:37:26
```

Added parameter `group_keys=False)` for avoid creating level from `number_from` column:

```
df2 = data1.groupby('number_from', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time'))
print (df2)
             id  number_from  number_to                time
Unnamed                                                    
17723    d210c4          396         48 2017-07-03 06:37:19
17703    d20c17          612        235 2017-07-03 06:36:28
17699    d20b3e          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:20
17700    d20b81          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:22
17701    d20b96          934        674 2017-07-03 06:36:23
17707    d20db5          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:45
17708    d20de9          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:47
17710    d20e05          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:49
17711    d20e41          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:51
17712    d20e73          934        658 2017-07-03 06:36:53
17713    d20ecc          934        702 2017-07-03 06:36:57
17714    d20ef1          934        702 2017-07-03 06:36:59
17715    d20f32          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:01
17716    d20f77          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:03
17717    d20f8d          934        702 2017-07-03 06:37:05
17718    d20fd8          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:08
17719    d21017          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:11
17720    d21032          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:12
17721    d2103e          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:13
17722    d2106d          934        262 2017-07-03 06:37:15
17725    d21147          934        691 2017-07-03 06:37:24
17726    d21167          934        691 2017-07-03 06:37:26
```

---

```
print (df1.equals(df2))
True
```

Comment: But I am also need to have a group, because I am doing later with each group separately. So the line: data1.sort_values(['number_from','time'], ascending=False).groupby('number_from') will do the work? :D

Comment: @Neven - It is alternative - first `'group'` by first sorting column and then sorting by another one.

Comment: @Neven - I think yes, for 100% sure not changed groups is possible use `data1.sort_values(['number_from','time'], ascending=False).groupby('number_from', sort=False)`

Comment: @Neven - Converting to datetimes is also necessay, just added to answer.

Comment: I just checked, I again have the same situation. :/ I do not know why. Should I maybe convert the column to integer numbers?

Comment: @Neven - hmmm, not idea. Are data confidental?

Comment: Yes. :/ 
I have seen now that you updated your answer. I will try it now the others solution from it. :)

Comment: @Neven - oops, just find problem I hope - need also convert numbers to integers by `data1['number_from'] = data1['number_from'].astype(int)`, in sample data not changed but in real data yes. Please check it.

Comment: I'am on it. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Now its ok. :))